# Strange CodeIgniter file upload error

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, mime-types, uploadify

I've set up 'Uploadify' to upload files to my server where I process them with CodeIgniter's file upload library.

However, I think Uploadify changes the mime type of the files, or does something else weird which causes CodeIgniter to give a 'the file type is not allowed' error despite it being allowed.

E.g I've allowed JPEG files but when I upload them using Uploadify, I get that error.

Is there any workaround for this? Basically, I want only image uploads to be allowed, e.g .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png. Do I have to manually check the extension of the files or is there any better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, uploadify uses the mime type `application/octet-stream` for most (all?) the files which it uploads.  I think this is actually caused by Flash handling the uploading, but I'm not 100% sure.

In your controller where you handle the upload, drop in a `print_r($_FILES)` and check out what the mime-type is, then just add it to your `application/config/mimes.php` file.

So in your `mimes.php` file you'll probably have something like:

```
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

Comment: The problem is that a user can figure out the url to which uploadify uploads, and then he can upload any malicious file manually to that url and pass on the mime type octet-stream, and it will be accepted. I've instead settled for `getImageSize()` to confirm if a file's an image or not.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue, unfortunately it is an issue with Uploadify.  Two possible solutions are recreating the uploaded image via PHP's GD library after the upload (any non-image file will throw an error) or find another upload script.

Comment: what about bmp file