# CodeIgniter File Upload Class - weird error behavior

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

So I'm using Codeigniter and I want to upload files. It's working fine except for this one thing.

Here's config code:

```
$this->conf = array(
    'max_size' => '1024',
    'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
    'allowed_types' => 'avi|mov|mpg|wmv|flv',
    'upload_path' => 'assets/media/videos/'
);
```

Uploading a 5MB mpg file, it shows the error `File is too big..`, but when I try to upload an 18MB mpg file, it just refreshes the page.

I'm at a loss here. I don't know where to start. Any helpful tips will be greatly appreciated. Also, let me know if I need to add more code, like I said, I've no idea where to start.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. changed upload max size on php.ini to 100M
2. the answer found here: [Strange CodeIgniter file upload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484289/strange-codeigniter-file-upload-error) but `print_r($_FILES)` doesn't even get executed, the page just refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not just upload max size, you'll want to up the following settings:

```
post_max_size
memory_limit
```

Also `set_time_limit` to something high as well or the upload is just timing out, hence why your seeing a blank array.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks. No idea why they still have `upload_max_filesize` in there, though. This was driving me nuts all day.